# How to increment a number from a csv and write over it

Tags: counter, talend

I'm wondering how to increment a number "extracted" from a field in a csv, and then rewrite the file with the number incremented.

I need this counter in a tMap.

Is the design below a good way to do it ?

[image: job layout]

EDIT: im trying a new method. see the design of my subjob below, but i have an error when i link the tjavarow to my main tmap in the main job

```
Exception in component tMap_1
java.lang.NullPointerException
at mod_file_02.file_02_0_1.FILE_02.tFileList_1Process(FILE_02.java:9157)
at mod_file_02.file_02_0_1.FILE_02.tRowGenerator_5Process(FILE_02.java:8226)
at mod_file_02.file_02_0_1.FILE_02.tFileInputDelimited_2Process(FILE_02.java:7340)
at mod_file_02.file_02_0_1.FILE_02.runJobInTOS(FILE_02.java:12170)
at mod_file_02.file_02_0_1.FILE_02.main(FILE_02.java:11954)
2014-08-07 12:43:35|bm9aSI|bm9aSI|bm9aSI|MOD_FILE_02|FILE_02|Default|6|Java
Exception|tMap_1|java.lang.NullPointerException:null|1
[statistics] disconnected
```

[image]

[image]

enter image description here

[image]

[image: TMAP1 in main job, where the error is]

Comment: hmmm i think i could output directly from the tmap to the tfileouputdelimied_4 ... and overwrite the counter.csv ?

Comment: You need to provide accurate screenshots if you want us to help. Your tMap configuration shows two inputs, row2 and row11 but your job layout shows a single input, row3.

Comment: i succeed but the counter do not loop with the Tfilelist at each file found. have to do the job one file by one file.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this mid flow in a tMap or a tJavaRow.

Simply read the number in as an integer (or other numeric data type) and then add your increment to it.

A really simple example might look like this:

[image: job layout]

Here we have a tFixedFlowInput that has some hard coded values for the job:

[image: data input]

And we run it through a tMap where we add 1 to the age column:

[image: tMap configuration]

And finally, we output it to the console in a table:

[image: data output]

EDIT:

As [Gabriele B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/696436/gabriele-b) has [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25162343/how-to-increment-a-number-from-a-csv-and-write-over-it/25162875#comment39176777_25162875), this doesn't exactly work when reading and writing to the same flat file as Talend claims an exclusive read-write lock on the file when reading and keeps it open throughout the job.

Instead you would have to write the incremented data to some other place such as a temporary file, a database or even just to the buffer and then read that data in to a separate job which would then output the file you want and clean up anything temporary.

The problem with that is you can't do the output in the same process. I've just tried testing reading in the file in one child job, passing the data back to a parent job using a tBufferOutput and then passing that data to another child job as a context variable and then trying to output to the file. Unfortunately the file lock remains on it so you can't do this all in one self contain job (even using a parent job and several child jobs).

If this sounds horrible to you (it is) and you absolutely need this to happen (I'd suggest a database table sounds like a better match for this functionality than a flat file) then you could raise a feature request on the [Talend Jira](https://jira.talendforge.org/secure/Dashboard.jspa) for the tFileInputDelimited to not hold the file open or to not insist on an exclusive read-write lock on the file.

Once again, I strongly recommend that you move to using a database table for this because even without the file lock issue, this is definitely not the right use of a flat file and this use case perfectly fits a database, even something as lightweight as an embedded [H2 database](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html).

Comment: I tihnk you cannot read and write a streaming file at the same time (not in Windows at least, in Unix you could probably do it using a named pipe); perhaps you need to buffer the file content somewhere and start writing it after the read was done...

Comment: @GabrieleB I was under the impression that Talend loads the file into memory and then closes it. I can check though...

Comment: @GabrieleB My bad. In a single subjob the tFileOutputDelimited will wipe the file (when not in append mode) before the tFileInputDelimited reads anything in. If the output is moved to a separate subjob then the input keeps a write lock on the file even after the input subjob is complete. You could output a temporary file with updated data and then probably delete that file and rename the temp one to match the old name in a separate child job.

Comment: I've toyed around with some options in Talend and it looks very unlikely that there's an easy way to do this using flat files as you will not be able to edit/delete the file you're reading in the same process. One option might be to have alternate files so to read from A and then output to B on run 1 then to read from B and output to A on run 2 etc but that's horrible. Your best bet is to use a database instead.

Comment: thank you all. i really prefer not to use a database, just to get a counter... H2 is embeddable with talend ? i build my jobs on windows and run them on ubuntu, H2 database will work in this way ?

Comment: You'd have to have a H2 database on both your Windows and Ubuntu machines but it's very lightweight (1.5 mb IIRC). Alternatively you might reconsider what you need the counter for or alternative implementations.